# Directory is being locked by windows service after first File.Move

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that monitors a directory for new files and, when a file is created/copied into that directory, it renames it and does some processing.

I'm using File.Move to rename the file.

It works fine when I use the exact same code from a console application, but now when it runs as a Windows Service.

Code that initialize the file watcher(s)

```cs
public void StartFileSystemWatcher()
        {
            listFileSystemWatcher = new List<FileSystemWatcher>();

            foreach (var customFolder in listFolders)
            {
                var dir = new DirectoryInfo(customFolder.FolderPath);

                if (customFolder.FolderEnabled && dir.Exists)
                {
                    var fileSWatch = new FileSystemWatcher
                    {
                        Filter = customFolder.FolderFilter,
                        Path = customFolder.FolderPath,
                        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
                        EnableRaisingEvents = true
                    };
                    fileSWatch.Created += (senderObj, fileSysArgs) => FileSWatch_Created(senderObj, fileSysArgs, customFolder.VSTSUrl);
                    listFileSystemWatcher.Add(fileSWatch);

                    logger.Info(string.Format("Starting to monitor files with extension ({0}) in the folder ({1})", fileSWatch.Filter, fileSWatch.Path));
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info(string.Format("File system monitor cannot start because the folder ({0}) does not exist", customFolder.FolderPath));
                }
            }
        }

private void FileSWatch_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e, string vstsUrl)
        {
            PostFileInfoToVSTS(e.FullPath, vstsUrl);
        }
```

Code that's run when the file is created

```cs
        private void PostFileInfoToVSTS(string filePath, string vstsUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                var fileParts = fileName.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                if (fileParts.Length == 6)
                {
                    //rename the file
                    var fileNewName = $"{fileParts[2]}.{fileParts[3]}.{fileParts[4]}.TXT";
                    var fileNewPath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)}\\oldfiles\\{fileNewName}";
                    File.Move(filePath, fileNewPath);

                    //prepare vsts request
                    var request = new VSTSRequest();
                    request.Variables.Region.Value = fileParts[0];
                    request.Variables.Sparc.Value = fileParts[1];
                    request.Variables.SystemName.Value = fileParts[2];
                    request.Variables.Type.Value = fileParts[3];
                    request.Variables.Name.Value = fileParts[4];
                    request.Variables.Filename.Value = fileNewName;

                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(vstsUrl);
                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSTSAuthentication"]);

                    //post to vsts
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }

                    //read response
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

                        logger.Info($"File '{fileNewPath}' processed. ReleaseId: {json.id}.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info($"File '{fileName}' wasn't processed. Name is not in the correct format.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

The first time I copy a file into that directory, it works fine, but the following times, I get a System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I can't seem to find your issue but that would only happen if you have not disposed of the reference to the file and you're attempting to write to it again which throws an error due to it being locked still by the first operation. At some point `File.Close()` need to be called

Comment: How are you sending the folder path, local folder, UNC file path, network share?

Comment: The file is being renamed in the same directory. It's a local path.